# How to access a file in a public directory using Zend Framework to integrate PayPal?

Tags: php, zend-framework, paypal, routes

I was given an application that needs PayPal to be integrated. I need PayPal to call a file residing in the public directory of the website (being hosted by GoDaddy).

Problem is when I try to access the file directly through the URL (example.com/public_html/file.php), I get this error:

"A 404 ERROR OCCURRED
PAGE NOT FOUND.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
NO EXCEPTION AVAILABLE"

I put the file there but I suspect that some routing stuff is preventing me (and PayPal) from accessing the file directly.

I read something about modifying .htaccess but I am not sure if that is the way to go. I have never used Zend Framework and was given this application to edit. I have been looking for an answer in the documentation for days but still no luck.

How can I modify Zend Framework's routing options so that this file can be accessed without a problem, if it's in the public_html/public/?

P.S.: There are other files, such as css files, that I can access without a problem. But the PHP and TXT files, I can't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Typically you wouldn't include public_html in your URL path.  Did you try example.com/file.php?

Comment: @AndrewAngell I did try that and I get the same error of "A 404 ERROR OCCURRED
PAGE NOT FOUND.
The requested URL could not be matched by routing.
NO EXCEPTION AVAILABLE"

Any other ideas? Again, I can access CSS files using example.com/public/css/dark.css (including the "public" in the URL).

Comment: If you have to include the /public_html directory in your URL paths then I'd say your server config needs adjusted.  In fact, it sounds like because of that, somebody setup .htaccess rules to handle URL rewriting and remove that from the URL for SEO purposes..??  That could cause issues loading a file directly like you're trying to do.